# Is it possible to not specify all template parameters if one of them is deduced?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-deduction

Suppose I have a function like this:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T& x);
```

I can use it without specifying the type because of the type deduction:

```
f(5.0f); // same as f<float>(5.0f);
```

Suppose I change the function:

```
template <typename T, int N>
void f(T& x);
```

I now have to call it like this even if the type can be deduced

```
f<float, 5>(5.0f);
```

But I'd like to have something like this:

```
f<auto, 5>(5.0f); // or something like f<5>
```

So far I've found a way to do this:

```
template <int N>
struct F {
    template <typename T>
    static void f(T& x) {
         ...
    }
}
```

So I can now use:

```
F<5>::f(5.0f);
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What are you ACTUALLY trying to do?

Comment: @MatsPetersson Why does it matter? This does not look like an XY problem.

Comment: the reason why @MatsPetersson asks this is that no, the language doesn't have this syntax `f<auto, 5>()` so the solution is to refactor, redesign or just leave it to always specify parameters. Depending on your problem you could reorder parameters, or use a struct as you have found or something else. But no general solution. Just workarounds tailored for specific problems.

Comment: 101010 answered the question without the details. It was indeed solved with changing the template argument order.

Comment: One plausible scenario would be `template<typename T, int N = 5> ...` also, but again, it depends on how what one wishes to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not change the order of template arguments:

```
template <int N, typename T>
void f(T& x) {
  // ...
}
```

And call it like:

```
double a;
...
f<1>(a);
```

Edit:

You could also provide two template overloads of your function with the template arguments in reversed order and with one default argument like below:

```
template <typename T, int N = 5>
void f(T& x) {
  // ...
}

template <int N, typename T = double>
void f(T& x) {
  // ...
}
```

And call it interchangeably:

```
double a = 4.0;
f(a);
f<2>(a);
f<double, 1>(a);
f<double>(a);
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29b61eed6a5729ab)

Comment: Didn't know that this is possible. Thanks! I'll accept it as soon as I can.

Comment: What if you sometimes wanted to use `f<10, auto>` and sometimes `f<auto, Foo>`?

Comment: @immibis `auto` specifier is not allowed as template argument.

Comment: @101010 why does reordering like this work by the way? I suppose this would work if I had more than two arguments, so I could have specified only some of them if the others were deduced?

Comment: @101010 You know perfectly well that `auto` is hypothetical syntax here.

Comment: It works because order of template arguments is independent of the order of template function parameters. The answer is yes, you can arrange the template arguments in a way that suits you, and specify some of them and have the rest been deducted.

Comment: @immibis suppose that I know it :), what's the purpose of your question?

Comment: @101010 The solution suggested here works if there's only one parameter you might want to deduce (or if all the deduceable parameters are after all the fixed parameters). Suppose sometimes you want to deduce only the first parameter, and sometimes only the second; what would you do then?

Comment: @immibis IMHO It's the same problem with function default argument parameters. Supposedly, you have a function `foo(int a = 1, int b = 2, int c = 3)`. And you want sometimes to assign values only for a and c but use the default value for b. How you would overcome this?